# Validate route params as array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Says user can go here `example.com/?page=1&q=123`

I can get 
`[{page: 1}, {q: 123}]`

using a library

But this is still can be dangerous says I want to use `[{page: 1}]` for something because the user can enter extra params which I don't need.

so the idea is I provide a preset
`const preset = [{page: 1}, {valid: true}]`

how can I get `[{page: 1}, {valid: true}] from says [{page: 1}, {valid: true}, {abc: 123}, {other: 'others'}]`?

Comment: This is an inconvenient way to retrieve route parameters. Most libraries would give you an object like `{page: 1, q: 123}`, which is much more efficient to use and makes a lot more sense. I'd be curious to know what framework is delivering route params like that.

Comment: `But this can be dangerous` I'm not really understanding the "dangerous" aspect of this. Can you try to make your example a little more clear, maybe by elaborating on the idea of what the purpose of a "preset" is and where the example input `[{page: 1}, {valid: true}, {abc: 123}, {other: 'others'}]` is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{page: 1}, {valid: true}, {abc: 123}, {other: 'others'}];
var result = arr.filter(x => Object.keys(x).includes('page') || Object.keys(x).includes('valid'));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `Object.keys` to iterate through the array and by checking key return obj

```js
const mixArray = [{page: 1}, {valid: true}, {abc: 123}, {other: 'others'}];

function filterRequiredObj(arr=[],filters=[]){
  return arr.filter((f)=>{
    const keys= Object.keys(f)[0];   
    if(filters.includes(keys)) return f
  })
}


const newArray = filterRequiredObj(mixArray,['page','valid'])
console.log('newArray',newArray)
```

Comment: I wrote as a function so that it can be reused in a similar scenario